# return array in rails and storage it

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, arrays

I know that it could sound an "easy-question" but I am new in rails and I don't know if I am structuring correctly my app.

My app is "easy" it has to connect a webpage and collect all JPG links and store the links in a database.

In my "model folder" I have defined my functions:

```
  class JPG < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_paranoid

    validates :title, :link, presence: true
    validates :link, uniqueness: true
    attr_accessible :tag_list, :id, :title
    #acts_as_taggable

     def main_web
      require 'rubygems'
      require 'scrapi'
      require 'uri'

      Scraper::Base.parser :html_parser 

      scraper = Scraper.define do
        array :items
        process "div.mozaique>div", :items  => Scraper.define {
          process "div.thumb>a", :link => "@href"

        }
        result :items
      end

      uri = URI.parse(URI.encode(web))
      return scraper.scrape(uri) 
    end
  end
```

As you can see the function `main_web` returns an array.

Well my question is "easy". If I want to call the function and to storage the information in the database, how do I have to do it?

I don't want to show the information in the screen I only want to storage the data in the database but from where do I have to do the call? view? or controller?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read more about the controller-view model. You need to call and store in the database from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

If main_web returns an array then wouldn't @jpg = @jpg.main_web mean that @jpg is now an array instead of the Active Record model? That would seem to be why it wouldn't save. You might want to add a field to your database that holds the array you generate from main_web. Then instead of returning it you could just call save on your @jpg model.

Also a nice tip would be if you are having issues with models or other things really try typing 'rails console' on command line. You could run your 3 lines of code there to see if they worked. This wouldn't solve your issue but might allow you to play around with some things.

```
@jpg = JPG.new
@jpg = @jpg.main_web
@jpg.save
```

Comment: Do you mean that it does not work in rails console or that it doesn't work with the first suggestion I gave. At the moment it should not be working in rails console so that is intended.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing my initial answer after giving it more consideration...

You are doing this:

```
return scraper.scrape(uri)
```

which you assign to the @jpg instance.  Thus, @jpg is no longer an instance of JPG and cannot be saved as such.

Also, it is not necessary to call and store from the controller.  The controller is more a decision maker than anything.  It determines state and routes control and information to the desired view or model.  The model is where data should be managed. Though, that may be a matter of debate and is my opinion.

Recommended reading:
http://sirupsen.com/what-I-wish-a-ruby-programmer-had-told-me-one-year-ago/